# ZXing.net for mobile is scanning phantom barcodes

Tags: xamarin.forms, zxing, zxing.net

I have a Xamarin.Forms app using ZXing.net mobile v3.  I've had zero issues until a user reported the camera just started acting like it scanned something without ever pointing the camera to a barcode. After some troubleshooting I was able to reproduce this, but only high sunlight areas.  It would scan the ground, scan the walls of a house etc... acting like it just scanned a barcode. Indoors, there is no issue.

This is on the iOS platform project.

Has anyone run into this before? Is there anything I can do about this? The main users of the app are normally outside.

Comment: Android or iOS?

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.  iOS, haven't tested on Android yet.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile#using-apples-avcapturesession-ios7-built-in-barcode-scanning

Comment: I have not, I am using xamarin.forms, I would have to create a custom renderer for the AV capture control.  Are you suggesting the AV capture engine is better than the ZXing engine?

Comment: I don't believe a custom renderer is required.  I'm just suggesting this as an alternative to try - the built in option may be more accurate

Comment: I see it now, in the options I can use `UseNativeScanning=true`.  I tried that and had the same result.  I did see where in previous versions of ZXing.net this property did nothing, but in v3 is should be using native AV capture engine.